# How to add to array on upsert

Tags: mongodb

I believe I have a classic case of "upsert" but need help with the update part.  I have blocks of text, one per db record.   I also have a potentially growing list of attributes that goes with each block of text --- so this where the upsert comes in.   I want to have something like:

```
{
     attr: ['red'],
     text: 'hello there'
}
```

and on the next upsert, it has to become:

```
{
    attr: ['red', 'green'],
    text: 'hello there'
}
```

So if the record is not found, insert it.  If the record is found, grow the attribute array with one additional attr.  Thank you

Comment: You have to use `$addToSet` not upsert

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet if I understand you correctly, $addToSet would be part of the update() command?  Initially, the record does not exist -- so update() inserts it and $addToSet is part of it. Correct?

Comment: `$addToSet` updates an array... If value is not exists in the array it does insert it

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
db.test.update(
  { "attr": { "$ne": "newColor" }},
  { "$addToSet": { "attr": "newColor" }},
  { "upsert": true }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this query:

```
db.test.update( {},
{
    $addToSet : {attr : "newColor"}
}
);
```

$addToSet adds the new value if it doesn't exist. If it exists, nothing happens :D
Hope it solves the problem.

Comment: thank you, but not quiet.   So what happened to the text field of the document? So if the entire document is not there (including text field), it gets inserted.   But if the document does exist, only the attr array gets appended to.

Comment: So, you want to add both the "attr" field and the "text" field, even if the whole document doesn't exist? Are you going to use some criteria to filter the update?